# How could the queen ensure that no Vosians left the planet?

Tags: aliens, slavery

So, on planet Vos, the insectoid species, the Vosians, have attracted many investors from across the galaxy. The investors have noticed that Vos has large, and I mean large, talutonium deposits, and everyone wants a piece of it. But, sadly, the Vosians are opposed to androids and automation, and don’t allow any robots on their planet. The Vosians agreed to give the investors access to the talutonium, but the Vosians worker drones would be the ones to mine the Talutonium.

They agreed, and now ***millions*** of Vosians toil away underneath the arid surface of Vos, doing backbreaking, intense labor. Dangerous labor. Mining lasers go critical and explode, caves and caverns collapse, and poisonous gas leaks kill the unprotected, unmasked workers. But, the workers are not a penny of money from all the mining they do. The queen and her hierarchy live lavishly, in palaces with all the nectar and ambrosia they want. The workers are now trying to leave their duties, angered at the fact that they're, essentially, slaves, not citizens on Vos. The fewer workers they have, the less money they make.

So, my question is, how could the queen stop Vosians from getting into cargo ships and leaving?

- Once the Vosian gets on the ship, the Queen can’t do anything. She can’t shoot it down, she can’t tractor beam it.
- If she does shoot down a cargo ship, the investors will sterilize the planet, killing all of them.
- Her plan, whatever it is, should be easy enough to be implemented within 3 months
- Vosians have no space travel, at least not at intergalactic levels.

Comment: I thought these were suppose to be a hive mind insect race? Why would the workers care about money? The hive is everything. They can't just leave and in all likelihood would just die from being alone.

Comment: @Thorne: Well, it’s not about money, it’s about the fact that they get blown or crushed into smithereens.

Comment: Worker bees die when they sting something. Dying isn't something a hive mind fears.

Comment: @Thorne: Yes, but they die for a useless cause.

Comment: Working for the betterment of the hive is a useless cause?

Comment: Doesn't the queen lay like 2,000,000 eggs a day? Why would they care that some sterile drones left if they don't care if some sterile drones die?

Comment: @Thorne: I never mentioned that in my question

Comment: It was in a previous question

Comment: @Thorne: Oh yes, you point is?

Answer (score 1):

Have the cargo holds of the ships be open to vacuum.  Don't let anyone you do not want to leave the planet into a pressurized compartment.  Good luck stowing away in hard vacuum.  If the Vosians are also the ones manning the ships, not just loading them, you will need a good way to tell the loaders from the crew.  Uniforms won't cut it here, a loader could easily steal or counterfit a crew uniform.  I recommend subcutaneous RFID chip implants that get scanned by every airlock.  If the crew are a different species, you can skip that.  Either way, you'll also need loyal guards to enforce it.  You'll need to search or X-ray all the crew's luggage to make sure no Vosians have stowed away in it.

Answer (score 1):

One tactic would be to never have the ships land in the place.

Scientifically speaking, getting a lot if cargo from a planet to space is really expensive if you use ships like America uses semi-trucks. The situation is like paying individual people to carry boxes up a completely vertical cliff just by climbing with the boxes strapped to their backs. It works, but it requires a lot of energy and a lot of trips,

Instead, the Volsian queens commisioned an elevator. A SPACE ELEVATOR.

[image]

Not only would this please the investors by making picking up the extracted cargo much cheaper, but it would mean that traitor workers have only a single possible escape route, rather than being able to pick from over a hundred landing cargo ships a day. Simply tighten up security where the space elevator makes contact with the planet, expose the cargo to hard vacuum during their assent (shout out to Ryan_L for that idea), and automate loading the material into the cargo ships. Then there's next-to-no way the uneducated slave class can make it to the freedom of starlight.

That last point breaks the no robots rule, but I'm hoping that doesn't hold sway several miles above the planets surface. This would also probably take more than three months to build, but I'd like to think the narrative potential of an elevator to freedom is worth stating regardless.

Comment: Well, pinion, these guys operate on 2500s tech, so three months could be enough ( ;